# How to switch variable into another variable once the condition is get in java if else if statement

Tags: javascript, java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I just want to know how to switch the variable into another variable.. For example, I have a an individual eggs... its 12 will consider as dozen eggs, in program, if I type 12 in individual eggs, how to put a code to switch it in dozen egg..

like this:

if (individualEggs==12)
convert it to dozenEggs:

the output in screen will be like this:
price of dozen egg = 1 usd
price of individual egg = .1 usd

dozenEggs = 1
individualEggs = 12

THE ANSWER MUST BE 2 USD
and not 2.2 usd... when it is computed.. please help me..

Comment: [tag:java] != [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 1):

Divide by `12` to get the number of full dozens you can get from the individual eggs. Take the remainder to get how many individual eggs are left, not forming a dozen.

```java
int dozenEggs = 1;
int individualEggs = 15;
dozenEggs += individualEggs / 12;
individualEggs %= 12;
// then calculate price, e.g. dozenEggs + individualEggs * .1
```